# How to tell if a GameObject is moving or not?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Well, I tried this:

```
{
    if(transform.position == m_transform) {
        stopped = true;
    }
    m_transform = transform.position;
}
```

But `stopped` is always `true` regardless of whether the object is moving or not. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If the target have `RigidBody` component, then you can check for

```
RigidBody.velocity == Vector3.zero
```

You can also check if target transform is changed -

```
if (transform.hasChanged)
{
    print("Target Moved.");
    transform.hasChanged = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say too much since you didn't share much code but from what I see, you want to detect if target is moving or not.

I think that can help you:

```
if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, newTarget.position) < 0.1f){
    //target stopped
}
```

So simply, if target is in range (means distance is very small) then we assume he stopped.